# Exception when trying to set GridViewColumn width

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

I got a `ListView`:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListViewAgentItems, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
              SizeChanged="ListView_SizeChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" Header="Agent ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AgentId}"/>
                <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}" Header="Distance" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Distance}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I want the `GridViewColumn` to take 50% of the width of the entire GridView instead of the default behavior in which the columns fit their width to the content. Of course that the `ListView` itself should also take the entire width of the column it's in.

So I've added that `SizeChanged` event:

```
private void ListView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView listView = sender as ListView;
        GridView gView = listView.View as GridView;

        var workingWidth = listView.ActualWidth - SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth; // take into account vertical scrollbar
        var col1 = 0.5;
        var col2 = 0.5;
        gView.Columns[0].Width = workingWidth * col1;
        gView.Columns[1].Width = workingWidth * col2;
    }
```

What happens is that the event keeps being called, and the value of `workingWidth` keeps getting smaller and smaller until it reaches a negative value, in which case I get an exception because a negative value can't be set to the width property. How can I solve this issue and get the result I want of 50% size to each column?

Comment: don't set the size of both columns, just set the size for 1 column, leaving the rest of the space for the other column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still better off using a datagrid than a listview.

When you set horizontalalignment the control will have an auto width.

Hence you calculate the size, the control adjusts and that changes it's size which fires the control again. Into a self propagating death spiral.

Try removing these two lines:

```
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
```

You might also do better handling the window sizechanged rather than listview.

This is roughly what a datagrid would look like:

```
    <DataGrid
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListViewAgentItems}" 
          >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                 Width="*"
                 Header="Agent ID" 
                 Binding="{Binding AgentId}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
                Width="*"
                Header="Distance"
                Binding="{Binding Distance}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Could you show a code example of how to define a datagrid with the way I want to achieve the columns?